# Python X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Tags: python, pygame, chromebook, thonny

I normally use Thonny as my go-to IDE for Python. Just until today, it worked fine. But it just doesn't work anymore for some reason. When I run my code, it does nothing except print this garbage in the terminal:

```
pygame 2.0.3 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.9.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  150 (XFree86-VidModeExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (XF86VidModeGetModeLine)
  Value in failed request:  0x21
  Serial number of failed request:  63
  Current serial number in output stream:  63

Backend terminated or disconnected. Use 'Stop/Restart' to restart.
```

I have no idea why this is happening or what caused it. I'm running this on a Lenovo Chromebook with an ARM64 processor, and I have Linux activated on it. I'm using pygame 2.0.3, Python is version 3.9.2, and Thonny is version 3.3.13. If I have to reinstall everything, so be it.

Comment: Can you share your code? Can you run it properly outside of Thonny? Have you upgraded Thonny or Pygame recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. All I had to do was powerwash my Chromebook and install everything all over again.